# What's the best way to use reactjs and rails asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, asset-pipeline, refluxjs

I'm using ruby on rails (with asset pipeline), reactjs (with [react-rails gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails)) and [reflux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs).

Currently I am defining all react components, reflux stores and actions as global variables in the javascript, so they are being declared in every page in my rails app.

I'm afraid that when I have hundreds of components and stores, the browser will have memory issues defining all these variables.

Is this really a problem? Is there a better way to use this stack along with the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

One good way is to separate React's components from Rails and just use the normal React ecology involving npm and webpack to inject an already transpiled JS file into your Rails asset pipeline.   This way Rails can still manage the overall use of assets for your pipeline, but doesn't have to directly generate the JS from React.  There are several descriptions from web pages about how to use webpack this way.  Personally, I use one found on GitHub by netguru called react_webpack_rails (https://github.com/netguru/react_webpack_rails), but you might not need a helper like this if you already know what you're doing with webpack and react.  There are other helper tools like this out there; you can look at https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial or http://www.railsonmaui.com/blog/2014/10/03/integrating-webpack-and-the-es6-transpiler-into-an-existing-rails-project/ for other discussions.

I'm not at all a fan of global variables in Javascript, so I found using a separate but integrated React-and-Rails approach like Netguru's to be the best way to handle it without cluttering up either my JS implementation or my Rails views.

As to your question about front-end "weight", I'd say that it doesn't matter yet.  Like most issues of speed or memory use, it's best to avoid pre-optimization.  When you encounter bottlenecks in real use, then refactor whatever is the greatest bottleneck iteratively until performance is acceptable again.   In any case, if you're doing a single-page app in React, you're probably putting as much load on the client as you do by resending each time with Rails' pages (ignoring the cost of the round trips themselves).  Just pay attention to profiling early on and monitor what you're doing, but don't prematurely optimize until it's obvious you need to.